# Filter columns based on the list of columns and list of values

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, tidyverse

Is there a way how to filter in R (using `tidyverse` or `data.table`) when having lists of columns and equal values?

One list contains columns to be filtered, the second list contains which values of columns on the first list shall be selected respectively.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(mtcars)

col1 <- c('mpg', 'am')
val1 <- c(21, 1)

# Pseudo idea of what I need
df %>%
  filter(col1 == val1)

# This is the results that shall be obtained by using col1 and val1

df %>% 
  filter(mpg == 21,
         am == 1)


col2 <- c('mpg', 'am', 'carb', 'vs')
val2 <- c(21, 1, 4, 0)

df %>%
  filter(col2 == val2)
```

However, it is very important that this should be generalizable and only filter condition will always be `==`.

ALSO, it needs to be automated so it work for lists with only one element e.g.:

```
col4 <- c('vs')
val4 <- c(0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the newer version of `dplyr`, we could also use `if_all` (equivalent to `all` i.e. it will return the rows where all the compound logical expressions are collapsed by `&` logical operator).  The one for `|` is `if_any`).  In this case, we can have a `named` vector` of 'val's

```
library(dplyr)
names(val1) <- col1
df %>%
    filter(if_all(all_of(col1), ~ . == val1[cur_column()]))
# A tibble: 2 x 11
#   mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#2    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
```

For the second case

```
names(val2) <- col2
df %>% 
    filter(if_all(all_of(col2), ~ . == val2[cur_column()]))
# A tibble: 2 x 11
#    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#2    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
```

Or for the one element vector

```
names(val4) <- col4
df %>% 
   filter(if_all(all_of(col4), ~ . == val4[cur_column()]))
# A tibble: 18 x 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
# 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
# 3  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
# 4  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
# 5  16.4     8  276.   180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0     0     3     3
# 6  17.3     8  276.   180  3.07  3.73  17.6     0     0     3     3
# 7  15.2     8  276.   180  3.07  3.78  18       0     0     3     3
# 8  10.4     8  472    205  2.93  5.25  18.0     0     0     3     4
# 9  10.4     8  460    215  3     5.42  17.8     0     0     3     4
#10  14.7     8  440    230  3.23  5.34  17.4     0     0     3     4
#11  15.5     8  318    150  2.76  3.52  16.9     0     0     3     2
#12  15.2     8  304    150  3.15  3.44  17.3     0     0     3     2
#13  13.3     8  350    245  3.73  3.84  15.4     0     0     3     4
#14  19.2     8  400    175  3.08  3.84  17.0     0     0     3     2
#15  26       4  120.    91  4.43  2.14  16.7     0     1     5     2
#16  15.8     8  351    264  4.22  3.17  14.5     0     1     5     4
#17  19.7     6  145    175  3.62  2.77  15.5     0     1     5     6
#18  15       8  301    335  3.54  3.57  14.6     0     1     5     8
```

---

Or another option is to create a single expression and parse it with `parse_expr`

```
library(stringr)
df %>%
   filter(!! rlang::parse_expr(str_c(col1, val1, sep = '==', collapse="&")))
```

Same approach for the second case as well

```
df %>%
   filter(!! rlang::parse_expr(str_c(col2, val2, sep = '==', collapse="&")))

# A tibble: 2 x 11
#    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#2    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
```

Or with the updated case

```
df %>%
  filter(!! rlang::parse_expr(str_c(col4, val4, sep = '==', collapse="&")))

# A tibble: 18 x 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
# 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
# 3  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
# 4  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
# 5  16.4     8  276.   180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0     0     3     3
# 6  17.3     8  276.   180  3.07  3.73  17.6     0     0     3     3
# 7  15.2     8  276.   180  3.07  3.78  18       0     0     3     3
# 8  10.4     8  472    205  2.93  5.25  18.0     0     0     3     4
# 9  10.4     8  460    215  3     5.42  17.8     0     0     3     4
#10  14.7     8  440    230  3.23  5.34  17.4     0     0     3     4
#11  15.5     8  318    150  2.76  3.52  16.9     0     0     3     2
#12  15.2     8  304    150  3.15  3.44  17.3     0     0     3     2
#13  13.3     8  350    245  3.73  3.84  15.4     0     0     3     4
#14  19.2     8  400    175  3.08  3.84  17.0     0     0     3     2
#15  26       4  120.    91  4.43  2.14  16.7     0     1     5     2
#16  15.8     8  351    264  4.22  3.17  14.5     0     1     5     4
#17  19.7     6  145    175  3.62  2.77  15.5     0     1     5     6
#18  15       8  301    335  3.54  3.57  14.6     0     1     5     8
```

---

Or can use `map2/reduce`.  Within the `filter`, loop over the 'col2', 'val2' values, subset the data based on the 'col2' check if it is equal to the corresponding 'val2' value, `reduce` the `list` of logical `vector`s into a single logical `vector` with `&` to `filter` the rows

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
  filter(map2(col2, val2, ~  cur_data()[[.x]] == .y) %>% reduce(`&`))
```

---

Or another option is to create the logical expression with `rowSums` after `select`ing the columns of interest from the dataset

```
df %>%
   filter(!rowSums(select(., col2) != val2[col(select(., col2))]))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
subset(df, Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, df[col2], val2)))
```

---

Can create a function to do this

```
f1 <- function(dat, colnms, vals) {

  dat %>%
     filter(map2(colnms, vals, ~  cur_data()[[.x]] == .y) %>%
      reduce(`&`))


 }
```

-testing

```
f1(df, col1, val1)
# A tibble: 2 x 11
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
2    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
f1(df, col2, val2)
# A tibble: 2 x 11
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
2    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
f1(df, col4, val4)
# A tibble: 18 x 11
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 4  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 5  16.4     8  276.   180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0     0     3     3
 6  17.3     8  276.   180  3.07  3.73  17.6     0     0     3     3
 7  15.2     8  276.   180  3.07  3.78  18       0     0     3     3
 8  10.4     8  472    205  2.93  5.25  18.0     0     0     3     4
 9  10.4     8  460    215  3     5.42  17.8     0     0     3     4
10  14.7     8  440    230  3.23  5.34  17.4     0     0     3     4
11  15.5     8  318    150  2.76  3.52  16.9     0     0     3     2
12  15.2     8  304    150  3.15  3.44  17.3     0     0     3     2
13  13.3     8  350    245  3.73  3.84  15.4     0     0     3     4
14  19.2     8  400    175  3.08  3.84  17.0     0     0     3     2
15  26       4  120.    91  4.43  2.14  16.7     0     1     5     2
16  15.8     8  351    264  4.22  3.17  14.5     0     1     5     4
17  19.7     6  145    175  3.62  2.77  15.5     0     1     5     6
18  15       8  301    335  3.54  3.57  14.6     0     1     5     8
```

Comment: Thank, I also added one comment so it shall work also for list with one element

Comment: @Petr It all works with the current solution.  Have you tested it